# Recharts bar chart y-axis range not rendered in case of multiple bar charts on same page

Tags: javascript, recharts

I am using 4 re-charts barchart control in react to display bar charts in the same page. To set the y-axis range, I am using datamax. It is working for 2 of the barcharts but for the remaining 2, it does not work. Below is the Y-Axis configuration:-

`<YAxis type="number" domain={[0, (dataMax) => Number(dataMax) + 50]} />`

Below is the screenshot of the way the charts are currently rendered. The ones highlighted in yellow are not correctly rendered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your json file has string values instead of numeric values. You can use parseInt(cost) or parseFloat(cost)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).